# Continuity of a simple eigenvalue and its corresponding eigenvector

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a square function valued matrix $A(\boldsymbol{t})$ whose entries are complex continuous functions of a vector of real parameters
$\boldsymbol{t}$, if  $\lambda_0$ is a simple eigenvalue at $\boldsymbol{t} = \boldsymbol{t}_0$ with a corresponding unit eigenvector $\boldsymbol{x}_0$, then for all $\boldsymbol{t}$ near $\boldsymbol{t}_0$ there is a corresponding eigenvalue and unique (normalized) eigenvector that are continuous in $\boldsymbol{t}$. I am looking for a proof or a counter example. I am especially interested in the case when $\boldsymbol{t}$ is a two dimensional vector.

Let $\boldsymbol{\Phi}$ be an $n \times n$ integer matrix with entries $\phi_{pq}\in\mathbb{Z}$. Moreover, let $\phi_{pp}=0$ (diagonal), $\phi_{pq} \neq 0$ (non-diagonal), 
$\phi_{pq} > 0;~\forall q>p$, $\phi_{pq} = -\phi_{qp}$ and gcd($\{\phi_{pq}\}_{q>p}$) $=1$. Let $\mathcal{X}$ denote the set consisting of all possible
$k \times k$ principle sub-matrices of $\boldsymbol{\Phi}$, with $2 \leq k \leq n$. Define $|\boldsymbol{A}|_{d+1} = \sum_{p=1}^{k-1} a_{pp+1}$ for any
$k \times k$ matrix $\boldsymbol{A}$. Furthermore, the matrix $\boldsymbol{\Phi}$ must also satisfy the constraint that $\forall \boldsymbol{X} \in\mathcal{X};|\boldsymbol{X}|_{d+1}=x_{1k}$, where $k$ is the dimension of $\boldsymbol{X}$.

Below I give the matrix that I am interested in. It is a rank 2 matrix most of the time. Its largest eigenvalue is always simple. I have an analytic expression for its largest eigenvalue. I need to know whether its normalized eigenvector is continuous?

Let $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{R}}(\boldsymbol{b})$ be an $n \times n$ Hermitian matrix (of continuous Hermitian functions) with entries
\begin{equation}
V_{pq}^{\mathcal{R}}(\boldsymbol{b}) = r_{pq}(\boldsymbol{b}) = A_1 + A_2e^{-2\pi i \phi_{pq}\boldsymbol{b}\cdot\boldsymbol{s}_0};A_1,A_2\in\mathbb{R},
\end{equation}
that is
\begin{equation}
V_{pq}^{\mathcal{R}}(u,v) = r_{pq}(u,v) = A_1 + A_2e^{-2\pi i \phi_{pq}(ul_0 + vm_0)}; u,v,l_0,m_0\in\mathbb{R},
\end{equation}
where $\phi_{pq}$ is the element found in the $p$-th row and $q$-th column of $\boldsymbol{\Phi}$, $\boldsymbol{b}=\left\langle u,v \right\rangle$ and $\boldsymbol{s}_0=\left\langle l_0,m_0 \right\rangle$. Furthermore let, $A_1=1,0<A_2<1$, $l_0 \neq 0, m_0 \neq 0$.

Its largest eigenvalue is 
$\lambda = \frac{n(A_1+A_2)}{2} + h$,

where $h=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{[n^2-4 {n \choose 2}][A_1+A_2]^2+4\sum_{p<q}(A_1^2+A_2^2+2A_1A_2\cos(2\pi\phi_{pq}\boldsymbol{b}\cdot\boldsymbol{s}_0))}$

Comment: It doesn't matter much that your parameter space is two-dimensional, and you could replace it with the single parameter $t=ul_0+vm_0$.

Answer (score 5):

It is a classical result that you can always manage for the eigenvalues to be continuous, even when they are multiple. For hyperbolic matrices (i.e. with real eigenvalues) the result of Bronshtein ensures Lipschitz continuity for the eigenvalues.

For your question in your framework the eigenvalue is smooth: with $p(X,t)$ be  the characteristic polynomial, you have at a simple root
$$
p(\lambda_0,t_0)=0,\quad \partial p/\partial X(\lambda_0,t_0)\not=0,
$$
so that you can use the implicit function theorem to get near $(\lambda_0,t_0)$ the equivalence
$$
p(\lambda,t)=0\Longleftrightarrow \lambda=\alpha(t),\alpha(t_0)=\lambda_0\text{ with a smooth function $\alpha$}.
$$

The eigenvectors could be very unstable at multiple roots. Consider the $2\times 2$ matrices
$$
A_1=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix},\quad A_0=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}
$$
and the smooth matrix
$
A(t)=H(-t)e^{-1/t^2}A_0+H(t)e^{-1/t^2}A_1,\quad H=1_{\mathbb R_+}.
$
The eigenvectors of $A(t)$ for $t<0$ are $e_1,e_2$ whereas the eigenvectors of $A(t)$ for $t>0$ are 
$$
e_1\pm  e_2,
$$ 
so the (normalized) eigenvectors are discontinuous.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I want to know what happens in the case that the eigenvalues are always distinct (no multiplicity). Are the eigenvectors continuous?

Comment: @trienko: Yes, in the case of simple eigenvalues the eigenvectors can be (locally, meaning if $t$ varies in a small disk) chosen to be continuous. However, if you want to choose them to be continuous functions on the entire set of (complex) values of $t$ for which all eigenvalues are simple, then there are obstructions.

Comment: What do you mean with obstructions? Do you have any literature on this (or references you can point me to)? I would appreciate this. I need to prove this theorem. $\boldsymbol{t}\in\mathbb{R}^2$. The matrix at each $\boldsymbol{t}$ is complex.

Comment: For my my matrix $\boldsymbol{A}(\boldsymbol{t})$ it seems to be continuous. Would it help if I define my matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Bazin's answer works for the general case, but the two-dimensional case is exactly solvable, which affords it a direct proof which may or may not be more useful in your case.

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&c\\b&d\end{pmatrix}$, and consider its eigenvalue equation
$$\det(\lambda-A)=\det\begin{pmatrix}\lambda-a&-c\\-b&\lambda-d\end{pmatrix}=\lambda^2-(a+d)\lambda+ad-bc=0,$$
whose general solution is
$$
\lambda=\frac{a+d\pm\sqrt{(a+d)^2+4(ad-bc)}}{2}=\frac{a+d}2\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{a-d}2\right)^2+bc}.
$$
The eigenvalues, then, are continuous functions of the matrix entries. If you ever come up on a branch cut you'll run out of eigenvalue but the other one will pop into existence there, which in practice means you can ignore the potential discontinuities of the square root.

Once you have an eigenvalue $\lambda$, you can get an eigenvector $x = \begin{pmatrix}u\\v\end{pmatrix}$ by solving
$$(\lambda-a)u-cv=0,$$
with the other equation automatically satisfied for $\lambda$ an eigenvalue, which means that 
$$x = u\begin{pmatrix}1\\ \frac{\lambda-a}{c}\end{pmatrix}
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\lambda-a}{c}\right)^2}}\begin{pmatrix}1\\ \frac{\lambda-a}{c}\end{pmatrix}
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{c^2+\left({\lambda-a}\right)^2}}\begin{pmatrix}c\\ {\lambda-a}\end{pmatrix}$$
is an eigenvector even when $c=0$, and depends continuously on $\lambda$ and the matrix entries. (In the complex case take squares of the moduli, and the last relation is only true up to a phase, but the end result is still a continuously-dependent eigenvalue).

This breaks only in the case that $c=0$ and $\lambda=a$ simultaneously, in which case the eigenvalue is not simple, which you've discarded, or the matrix is diagonal. In this case, there's more you can say about the eigenvalue, because $a$ and $d$ are bounded from each other but $c$ is zero or small, in which case
$$
\lambda=\frac{a+d}2 + \left(\frac{a-d}2\right)\left(1+\frac{2bc}{(a-d)^2}+O(b^2c^2)\right)=a+\frac{bc}{(a-d)}+O(b^2c^2).
$$
Plugging this back in and rearranging, you get that 
$$x 
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{b^2}{(a-d)^2}+O(c)}}\begin{pmatrix}1\\\frac{b}{a-d}+O(c)\end{pmatrix}$$
is your eigenvalue, and again it's continuous at $c=0$ as long as $a$ is bounded from $d$.

The take-home message, then, is that the two-dimensional case is very often amenable to direct manipulations that make you not need the general results for higher dimensionality. If you do things carefully enough, this can usually help you understand your problem better anyway (though if you don't it will get messy fast).

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. I however require a definite answer for $n$ dimensions. The vector $\boldsymbol{t}$ can be two dimensional. From experimental data it seems that the above theorem is true, as long as the eigenvalue is simple $\forall \boldsymbol{t}\in\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Oh. Apologies, I misread the question. The special case is when the matrix itself is two-dimensional. The dimensionality of the space of parameters is not that relevant; most such results will prove continuity on the matrix entries. For a higher dimensionality of your parameter space, though, you should be aware that avoided crossings will in general turn into conical intersections, which are trickier to deal with.

Comment: Do you know of any literature dealing with the above issue?

Comment: I would start with Wikipedia, or whatever quantum chemistry textbook you're able to plough through. It's hard to know if it will be an issue without knowing more about your matrix.

Comment: I added the details of my matrix, could you please have a look at it? Maybe you could spot a possible issue. All the other eigenvalues are always smaller than its largest eigenvalue $\forall \boldsymbol{b}\in\mathbb{R}^2$. It would really help me tremendously.