# Formula for eigenvector corresponding to a simple eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, numerical-linear-algebra

In a book on numerical linear algebra (Deuflhard numerische Mathematik Band 1) there is the following exercise (translated from German):

> Give a Formula (using Determinants) for an eigenvector $x \in \mathbb{C}^n$ corresponding to a given simple eigenvalue $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ of a Matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$.

It really should be a formula and not an algorithm, since the formula is to be used to show that the eigenvector depends on the matrix in a continuous differentiable fashion.
My problem is that any formula I think of yields $0$ instead of a proper eigenvector

Any ideas on how to get such a formula?

Comment: When you say that "an eigenvector depends on the Matrix in a continuous differentiable fashion", it is meaningless as such because an eigenvector is defined up to a factor. The less you can do is to normalize your eigenvectors (normed to unity).

Comment: @JeanMarie what I mean is that there exists a continuously differentiable function which maps every $A \in U \subset \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ to one of its eigenvectors (the fact that the eigenvalues "are continuously differentiable" was established before in the book). Obviously this function won't be unique but I don't see any other problem.

Comment: I understand a little more. See similar question with answer (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/807144)

Comment: see as well the second answer in (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/581057)

Comment: ... and (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/253584/differentiability-of-eigenvalue-and-eigenvector-on-the-non-simple-case)