# A "repeated roots allowed" version of the continuity of roots

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, continuity

Let $R_n$ denote the set of all monic real polynomials of degree $n$
all of whose roots are real. Then $R_n$ is a closed subset of the
$n+1$-dimensional space ${\mathbb R}_n[X]$. For $P\in R_n$, denote by
$\theta_1(P) \leq \theta_2(P) \leq \ldots \leq \theta_n(P)$ the roots
of $P$ in increasing order. Is the map $(\theta_1,\theta_2, \ldots,\theta_n):
R_n \to {\mathbb R}^n$ continuous? This is true for $n=2$.

I know about more usual "continuity of roots" properties (see for example
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63196/continuity-of-the-roots-of-a-polynomial-in-terms-of-its-coefficients) ), but I don’t see
clearly how they might be useful here. Most versions only deal with
polynomial without repeated roots.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. I've not worked through the technical difficulties in making a direct proof, so I'll cheat and suggest that you construct the [companion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix), and use the fact that [you can write the eigenvalues as continuous functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/581058/14972). (I don't have a better reference off hand)

All that remains is to show that if you have $n$ continuous functions $f_i(x)$, that if you let the list $g_i(x)$ be the reordering of the values of the $f_i(x)$ from least to greatest, that the $g_i$ are also continuous.

Comment: The reordering issue is easy : the functions $\min$ and $\max$ are continuous ${\mathbb R}^2 \to {\mathbb R}$, because $\min(x,y)=\frac{x+y-|x-y|}{2}$ and $\max(x,y)=\frac{x+y+|x-y|}{2}$